# rails: how to store values from model1 inside model2 upon creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, delegates

Creating a Student with a Match both are models and I would like to store values from Student inside Match. How should one approach this?

I tried delegate but that throws error that match is empty, any ideas? Thanks!

**user model:**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :level

  has_one :match
  before_create :setup_match

  def setup_match
    self.create_match # create the match that belongs to this student
  end


end
```

**match model:**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :student
  attr_accessible :initiated, :level

  before_save :default_values

  def default_values
    # HERE is the problem
    # Need to store student.name and student.level here, how?
    self.initiated = student.name
    self.level = student.level
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move setting values for Match in the Student.. something like this (not tested):

```
class Student < AR::Base
  has_one :match
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :match

  before_create :setup_match

  def setup_match
    build_match(:initiated => name, :level => level)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks alot after trying some variations i ended up with working solution